# Why was this user awarded my bounty, when all 3 answers had the same number of upvotes?

Tags: support, bounty

I posted a bounty question:  [Should mobile apps flip upside down?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/133970/should-mobile-apps-flip-upside-down)

There was a three way tie in upvotes: +2, +2, +2.

It selected one user to award the bounty.  Why was it awarded to that user, when there was a three way tie?  Were they selected at random?

Potential factors:

- I upvoted all three answers.
- The bountied answer was the second upvote I issued.
- The bountied answer is the longest answer.
- The bountied answer has no comments, while another answer does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's awarded to the oldest answer (posted within the bounty period).

From the Help Center article [What is a bounty? How can I start one?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/bounty):

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount (or the full amount, if the answer is also accepted). If two or more eligible answers have the same score (their scores are tied), the oldest answer is chosen. If there's no answer meeting those criteria, no bounty is awarded to anyone.

Comment: Ah, it was not the oldest answer...but must have been the oldest answer since the bounty was issued.  Thanks!  Curiosity quenched.